# Adding "not dead" in Browserslist for Babel produces different results, even though browsers are the same?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

My config is:

```
last 10 versions, not < 0.1%, not dead, not ie > 0, not op_mini all, not edge < 70, not samsung < 9
```

I tried removing `not dead`

```
last 10 versions, not < 0.1%, not ie > 0, not op_mini all, not edge < 70, not samsung < 9
```

Running `npx browserslist` produces the exact same results for both:

```
and_chr 87
and_ff 83
and_qq 10.4
and_uc 12.12
chrome 87
chrome 86
chrome 85
chrome 84
chrome 83
chrome 81
chrome 80
chrome 79
chrome 77
edge 87
edge 86
firefox 83
firefox 82
firefox 81
firefox 78
ios_saf 14.0-14.2
ios_saf 13.4-13.7
ios_saf 13.3
ios_saf 13.0-13.1
ios_saf 12.2-12.4
ios_saf 12.0-12.1
ios_saf 11.3-11.4
ios_saf 10.3
opera 72
opera 71
safari 14
safari 13.1
safari 13
safari 12.1
samsung 13.0
samsung 12.0
samsung 11.1-11.2
samsung 9.2
```

However, the bundle size for Webpack + Babel is 20% bigger without `not dead`. Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the `last 10 versions` are dead and get removed when you add `not dead`.

Comment: You're saying `npx browserslist` includes browsers that are ignored?

Comment: Looks that way, your config is ambiguous so different tools will have differing results